# How to configure trusted proxy middleware for Heroku on Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, heroku

Heroku has the following documentation for configuring trusted proxies when working with Laravel:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#trusting-the-load-balancer

It says:

> It is very important to also prevent Laravel from trusting the
>   Forwarded and X-Forwarded-Host headers, because Heroku’s router does
>   not set those, but Symfony’s Request component trusts them out of the
>   box once a trusted proxy is set.
>
> The final configuration file should look like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'proxies' => '*',
    'headers' => [
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED    => null, // not set on AWS or Heroku
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  => null, // not set on AWS or Heroku
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
        Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT  => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    ]
];
```

Laravel has it's own documentation on how to configure trusted proxies:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

I'm confused because as you can see in the example from the Laravel docs here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = [
        '192.168.1.1',
        '192.168.1.2',
    ];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

The `$headers` property is a string, not an array. I was expecting to see an array where I can add the header mapping just like the Heroku docs say, but I don't see how I would do that with `$headers` string property.

What is the appropriate way to set up this middleware for Heroku so that I can still "prevent Laravel from trusting the `Forwarded` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers" as Heroku recommends?

Answer (score 1):

First, some background. You probably know this first part though.

The Heroku docs still refer to the time when TrustedProxy had not yet been brought into the laravel core itself which happened with 5.5.  Since 5.5, we do these settings via the middleware included in Laravel, not by publishing the config file from trusted proxy as we did before 5.5 (which incidentally you can still do off of that package since it's installed - but shouldn't if you're on 5.5+ The docs confused me on that initially.). I think you got all that though.

On the main substance of your question.

I run 5.5 LTS (on Heroku) myself so I don't have this exact problem -  on 5.5, the `$headers` property is still an array as seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies).

In 5.6 symfony was upgraded to version 4 which changes a lot.  The 5.6 docs link to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html) which could be what to look at.

Sorry this isn't a full answer at this point. Thought I'd just set out what I know, hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks but yes this is basically everything I have already realized which is why I am asking the question. Still not clear has on how to appropriately set the headers variable.

Comment: They changed it to a bit field instead of an array. Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL looks equivalent to trusting all five when it was an array. That page says you can pass a bit field. Looks like you need to pass a bit field trusting only the three of the five that Heroku sets. Could be 0b01011.  So try that as your value for $headers?  How to be sure it's correct of course...  interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies), this is what you should pass:

`HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB`

It makes reference to AWS ELB, but it should be the same for Heroku as it does not send "X-Forwarded-Host"